# Chosing correct frequency axes

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I want to have amplitude and phase reconstruction of the signal. My signal is having 40KHz bandwidth and starting frequency is 70Khz to 110 KHz. Suppose my signal is `x`.

```
nfft = length(x);
res  = fft(x,nfft)/ nfft;                     % normalizing the fft
f    = fs/2*linspace(0,1,nfft/2+1);           % choosing correct frequency 
res  = res(1:nfft/2+1);                       % amplitude of fft
res2 = fft(res);
```

I want to plot frequency versus amplitude using

```
figure
plot(f,abs(res2))
```

where the amplitude should be lying from the 70kHz to 110kHz and similarly for the frequency versus phase

```
figure
plot(f,angle(res2))
```

the phase should be spread over 70kHz to 110kHz. So how to chose the correct frequency axes.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to plot the frequency content of the signal `x` and not the frequency content of the already transformed signal `res`, then you should get rid of the line

```
res2 = fft(res);
```

The `plot(f,abs(res))` and `plot(f,angle(res))` would then correctly show your signal from 0 to `fs/2`.

You can then zoom more closely on the 70kHz-110kHz frequency range of interest (assuming `fs/2>110000`) using:

```
axis([70000 110000]);
```

Comment: Hi SleuthEye, i do not want to see the beat frequency. I want to plot the frequency versus amplitude. plot(f,abs(res2)); second fft gives me box function. However, since its not a ideal signal therefore i am not getting exactly box shape of my amplitude. Now i want this amplitude to spreaded over my bandwidth.